# app goes slow down when i try to add image view inside appbarlayout or CollapsingToolbarLayout. why?

Tags: android

when i adding this image view my app goes slow down. i mean it takes much time to swiping and scrolling then regular

here is my code,m just trying to make simple collapsing toolbar app,please help me out

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="#607D8B"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pager_image"
            android:background="#607D8B"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#22000000"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#22000000"
            app:tabTextColor="#FFC107"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/car"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there could be two reasons which related to your image content

- either the size of your images is to much larger
- or the dimensions of image is not proper(ration of lenght*width). thats why it takes time to fit properly to layout in case you have more images